# What is wrong with this triple for loop that is expressing a triple summation?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In Algorithm Design Manual Chapter 2 Exercise 4, the following pseudo code is given

```
function conundrum(n)
   r := 0
   for i := 1 to n do
      for j := i + 1 to n do
         for k := i + j − 1 to n do
            r := r + 1
   return(r)
```

It can be expressed as the following triple summation.

[image]

The closed form of this triple sum is (1/2)(n-1)(n).

My code is as follows. **For n > 3, my triply nested for loop is returning an incorrect result, but I can't figure out why.**

```js
const conundrum = n => {
    let r = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
            for (let k = i+j-1; k <= n; k++) {
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}

const conundrumClosedForm = n => {
    return (1/2)*(n-1)*n;
}
console.log(conundrum(3) === conundrumClosedForm(3));
console.log(conundrum(4) === conundrumClosedForm(4));
console.log(conundrum(5) === conundrumClosedForm(5));
```

[Here is the answer I am reading from chegg.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJCBe.png)

[Here is the question itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0yQV.png)

Comment: That's not the correct closed form equation.

Comment: That's the formula for the sum of 1..n, not the triple-nested sums.

Comment: @Barmar that is the answer the book gives for the closed form equation and its what wolfram alpha is giving me https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%28sum%281%2C+%7Bk%2Ci%2Bj-1%2Cn%7D%29%2C+%7Bj%2Ci%2B1%2Cn%7D%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Cn%7D%29

Comment: also the formula for 1..n is  n(n+1)/2

Comment: That means your closed form is the sum of 1..(n-1).

Comment: the book and wolfram are both getting the same exact incorrect answer? that doesnt seem likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're looking at the wrong articles, or your WolframAlpha-fu is not in tune today.

The following JavaScript shows that the sequence being generated is the one shown at [A173196](https://oeis.org/A173196), which states that the *n*th element is given by `a(n) = (4*n^3 + 6*n^2 - 4*n - 3 + 3*(-1)^n)/48`:

```js
function S(n) {
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (let j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
                for (let k = i+j-1; k <= n; k++) {
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }

    return sum

}

function D(n) {
    return (4 * n * n * n + 6 * n * n - 4 * n - 3 + 3 * Math.pow(-1, n)) / 48
}

for (let q = 0; q <= 10; q++) {
    console.log(q + " " + S(q) + " " + D(q))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you sure that (1/2)(n-1)(n) is correct?

Let's check sums for n = 4:

```
(1/2)(4-1)4=(1/2)*3*4=6
```

Let's check loops:

iteration 1:

i = 1, j = 2, k = 2 - it will make r = 4

iteration 2:

i = 2, j = 3, k = 4 - it will make r = 16 > 6

So, after the second iteration our sums will be greate than (1/2)*(n-1)*n.

Comment: the closed form is correct https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%28sum%281%2C+%7Bk%2Ci%2Bj-1%2Cn%7D%29%2C+%7Bj%2Ci%2B1%2Cn%7D%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Cn%7D%29